# HttpPost fileupload data loss

Tags: android, httpclient

From my app I upload a file to our server using this basic code (it is a bit more than this of course but this is basically it)

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams(); 
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 15000); 
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 5 * 60 * 1000); 
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params); 
HttpPost  post = new HttpPost("upload url"); 
HttpEntity requestEntity = (new FileEntity(tmpFile, "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary); 
post.setEntity(requestEntity); 
HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) client.execute(post);
```

That works fine MOST of the time.

For some phones running Android 2.2+ the file received on the server 
side is not complete.  Small portions of the file are simply missing, 
and the parts that are missing are at different locations of the file 
each time.

We have verified this by comparing the file from the app against what 
is received on the server side.  On the server side we captured 
packets with tcpdump to make sure it wasn't an issue with our web 
server or web server code.

We also checked the data with tcpdump from the phone.  The tcpdump file from the phone DOES differ from the data we are trying to send.  For one case we did analysis on the tcpdump file is missing data between the address 8d68 and 9000 from the file.  The packets from tcpdump line up with those addresses (one packet has a portion of the data up until 8d68 and then the next packet has data starting from 9000).

For these phones the problem only happens some of the time.  Sometimes 
file uploads work and the entire file is received intact on our end.

This is happening ONLY for 2.2+ phones.  It happens for a wide variety 
of phones, and a variety of carriers, and for hundreds of users.   It appears to happen over both wifi and 3g based on the IP addresses seen on the server side.

This is anecdotal but when trying to get this to happen on my Nexus over the past 2 days I have seen it happen 6 times and those times are always right around when I am entering or leaving the room close to a certain wifi router.  The rest of the day when I'm in the office on a different wifi router or on a cell network the issue never happens.  My theory being that the app is busy sending data and now we move from wifi to cell network or vice versa, is that a dumb idea or a possibility?

I can put the tcpdump files and data files up somewhere if anyone cares to take a look.

What else should I be investigating to figure out the reason for this?

Comment: as i already said, if you can repeat this bug on your phone, install tcpdump and see what exactly is leaving your phone. this way you will be sure it's not the application

Comment: Hi Alex, I finally did figure out how to reproduce the bug on my phone on occasion and have captured the result with tcpdump on my phone.  The tcpdump DOES differ from the file I am trying to send (i edited the original question above with the details).  Any ideas what to try now?

Comment: quite strange actually. if you run tcpdumb on your phone, it logs what the phone sends out. doubt it have anything with your network. you can try to use something other than httpmime. use streams. this way you can be 100% sure you send correct data as you do it yourself and don't rely on other libraries.. i myself would do it first... then if it still happens. a prayer maybe? :)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing some similar issue when uploading the binary data. I figured out that it was a problem with the server code. 
There were some filters at the server side, which were reading the incoming requests and trying to log them. The code was trying to put the incoming stream in some String type of DS. Its was because of this that the binary images were distorted.
Just check if there are any filters at the server side. Hope this helps