# Android: Sending a byte[] array via Http POST

Tags: android, http-post

I am able to do a POST of a parameters string. I use the following code:

```
String parameters = "firstname=john&lastname=doe";
URL url = new URL("http://www.mywebsite.com");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
out.write(parameters);
out.flush();
out.close();
connection.disconnect();
```

However, I need to do a POST of binary data (which is in form of byte[]).

Not sure how to change the above code to implement it.
Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These links might be helpful:

- [Android httpclient file upload data corruption and timeout issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896949/android-httpclient-file-upload-data-corruption-and-timeout-issues/4896988#4896988)
- http://getablogger.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-how-to-post-file-to-php-server.html
- http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?108546-How-do-I-post-a-byte-array

Answer (score 9):

Take a look here
[Sending POST data in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android)

But use ByteArrayEntity.

```
byte[] content = ...
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(content));           
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: It is taking a very long time (8 sec) to execute this line "httpPost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(content));" sometimes in my code. Do you have any idea why this can happen ?

Answer (score 6):

You could base-64 encode your data first. Take a look at the aptly named [Base64](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) class.

Comment: +1 for the idea. Unfortunately I cannot do use Base64 since the server does not expect it. (I cannot make change to the server as it caters to many client applications)