# How to display .jpg image from blob in .jpg link

Tags: php, mysql

I've a issue. I want to display .jpg image from blob.

I can display it in scripts. For example...

```
<?php
 $db = mysqli_connect('xxxxx', 'xxxxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxxx');
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
 foreach ($db->query("SELECT * FROM `pictures` WHERE imageID = 3") as $result) {

 header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

 $img = $result['img'];
 print $img;
 }
?>
```

In index page is this link:

```
echo '<img src="/wszystko/obiektowy_obrazki/img.php">';
```

And now... I want to display It by this link:

```
echo '<img src="/wszystko/obiektowy_obrazki/$img.jpg">';
```

How can I do It?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Can i do it without storing .jpg files locally on the server?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<img src=\"/wszystko/obiektowy_obrazki/$img.jpg\">";
```

OR

```
echo "<img src='/wszystko/obiektowy_obrazki/$img.jpg'>";
```

Or (more cleaner)

```
$path = '/wszystko/obiektowy_obrazki';
$image = $path . '/' . $img . '.jpg';
print '<img src="' . $image . '">';
```

Comment: Yes. That's it. But $img is extract from data base in blob.

Comment: @KrzysztofSikora so you have a stored image that was encoded with base64 ?

Comment: Yes. blob, base64 into mysql database

Comment: Ok, so please see my answer that i've written in another thread. if it's what you're looking on so upvote it that i can close this question as duplicate... the goal is to keep SO as clean as possible :) Ok ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/36037835/4098311