# how to convert mp3 file to bytes and sent to java webservice. in android?

Tags: android

I have recorded a file and saved it in sdcard as mp3.Now I need to send that file to webservice.How can I acheive that?Pls give some ideas.

I need to convert the mp3 file to byte array and pass to webservice.How can I pass the file to java webservice.

Comment: What kind of web service? Something you control? Someone else's service? If the latter, there should be some documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do some googling on it, you can found many blogs, SO question and tutorials..

OK fine just go through these..

[Android: Upload image or file using http POST multi-part](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/)

[Sending pictures to a web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415390/sending-pictures-to-a-web-server)

[Android httpclient file upload data corruption and timeout issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896949/android-httpclient-file-upload-data-corruption-and-timeout-issues)

Comment: If you are use httpmime-4.1-beta1.jar for you upload file then I think you don't have to convert file into bytes it does in background but I think it depends on your webservice how it handles the request. And here you didn't give any details about web service.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the MP3 data into it's Base64 equivalent and then send it as a String. On the server,decode it accordingly.

Comment: @Thilo, My answer still stands. [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893/how-do-you-embed-binary-data-in-xml) for more info.