# How to upload a byte array from java to PHP server

Tags: java, php, laravel-4, arrays

I have a specific problem that when I upload a picture from my client side (Java) to be stored in the server (PHP).

I am getting the byte array from my image scanner, I want to send this byte array from Java to my server (which is Laravel 4.2) and store it as a blob in an Oracle database.

I am new to Java. How can I accomplish this? Thanks for guiding me.

Comment: You can use HttpURLConnection

refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/21322465/4353919

Comment: You could use a socket connection?

Comment: I think Laravel 4.2 handle API calls effectively, so can I make a POST url with byte array from java?